# How to remove unwanted form state values before validation

Tags: 8, forms

What is the good way of validating a form in Drupal 8 ?

I have a bunch of fields which are supposed to be filled by a positive numeric value (and that's all, no other input types, just positive int).

```
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
$values = $form_state->getValues();

foreach ($values as $method => $fee) {
  if ($method != 'Free order') {
    if (!is_numeric($fee) || floatval($fee) < 0) {
      $form_state->setErrorByName($method, t('Value must be a positive integer.'));
    }
  }
}
```

}

The issue is when using `$form_state->getValues()` it also returns "submit", "form_token", "form_build", "form_id", "op" which is quite boring as those infos are not needed for performing validation.

So what I did is removing those four unwanted values with :

```
$values = array_splice($values, count($values) - 5, 5);
```

But it's really annoying, am I doing something wrong, or is just as it ? Because I think those values are really not necessary in the validation process.

Comment: The answer is correct, but there are two other alternatives that you might want to consider. a) If this is really everything you need, then just use #type number and #min => 0. That will cover that validation automatically, it will also do it already in the browser and e.g. mobile clients will automatically show a number-only keyboard. Everyone wins. b) Or, consider putting your elements inside a common key, just do something like $form['numbers']['#tree'] = TRUE, put them below that in the array and then $form_state->getValue('numbers') and you just get your elements, no cleaning necessary.

Comment: I was struggling a bit about how to get floated values with the 'number' field type. You actually have to put a '#step' of 0.01 for example if you want 2 decimal after the integer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `FormState` class has a method for that: [`FormState::cleanValues()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AcleanValues/8.6.x). From its description, it's the method you should use.

> This function can be used when a module wants to store all submitted form values, for example, by serializing them into a single database column. In such cases, all internal Form API values and all form button elements should not be contained, and this function allows their removal before the module proceeds to storage. Next to button elements, the following internal values are removed by default.
>
> - form_id
> - form_token
> - form_build_id
> - op

You simply call it before getting the submitted values.

```
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $values = $form_state->cleanValues()->getValues();

  foreach ($values as $method => $fee) {
    if ($method != 'Free order') {
      if (!is_numeric($fee) || floatval($fee) < 0) {
        $form_state->setErrorByName($method, t('Value must be a positive integer.'));
      }
    }
  }
```

Since `FormState::cleanValues()` returns the `FormState` object, you can simply call it in the same line you call  `FormState::getValues()` concatenating the two calls.

If you need to add more keys to remove from the submitted values, you could use [`FormState::setCleanValueKeys()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetCleanValueKeys/8.6.x), but keep in mind that:

- The array passed to the method needs to contain also the default array keys Drupal would remove
- The method alters the array keys that are removed from `FormState::cleanValues()` for every Drupal form